# Disable Controller API Endpoint For Production

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What is a recommended way to allow a restful endpoint api or even a controller to be exposed in Development but upon publishing to other environments it is not made available?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. You'd have to do something like inject `IHostingEnvironment` into your controller and then do a check like the following in your action:

```
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
{
    return NotFound();
}
```

That would then give the *appearance* that the route didn't actually exist outside of the development environment. If you're going to be doing this enough, it would probably actually be better to create a custom resource filter that you could apply:

```
public class DevelopmentOnlyAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var env = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Which you could then apply to the relevant actions like:

```
[DevelopmentOnly]
public IActionResult Foo()
```

Comment: can't we use @Profile attribute at rest controller and enable it for development?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. There's no `Profile` attribute.

Comment: sorry I mean @Profile annotation at class level.

Comment: Note that `IHostingEnvironment` is deprecated and `IHostEnvironment` should be used instead. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601958/ihostingenvironment-is-obsolete)

Answer (score 2):

One can also set the controller action (or the full controller) behind a feature flag, enable it in the Development environment and keep it disable in the Production environment until the feature/endpoint is ready.

1. Install Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore NuGet package
2. Declare your feature flags in `appsettings.json` or another config source

```json
{"FeatureManagement": {
        "FeatureA": true, // Feature flag set to on
        "FeatureB": false, // Feature flag set to off
    }
}
```

3. Configure DI service
   `builder.Services.AddFeatureManagement();`
4. Decorate controller action (or full controller)

At controller level:

```
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement.Mvc;

[FeatureGate("FeatureA")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

At controller action level:

```
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement.Mvc;

[FeatureGate("FeatureA")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

See [Tutorial for using feature flags in a .NET app | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core6x)