# 'IHostingEnvironment' is obsolete

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I updated my ASP.NET Core project to .NET Core v3.0.0-preview3, and I now get:

> Startup.cs(75,50,75,69): warning CS0618: 'IHostingEnvironment' is
>   obsolete: 'This type is obsolete and will be removed in a future
>   version. The recommended alternative is
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment.'

The code is:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    …
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to do this now? Are there any documentation or examples to demonstrate that?

Comment: It seems `IHostingEnvironment` has been replaced by `IHostEnvironment` (and a few others). See [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749) on GitHub

Comment: great thanks, all I had to do was to replace `IHostingEnvironment` with `IHostEnvironment` and add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` .. if you want to post an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Some places i see method `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` and in some projects I start, the default is `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`. Whats the difference?

Comment: Well now it's right there in the warning, isn't it: `"The recommended alternative is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment."`

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It seems `IHostingEnvironment` has been replaced by `IHostEnvironment` (and a few others).
You should be able to change the interface type in your code and everything will work as it used to  :-)

You can find more information about the changes at this link on GitHub
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749

EDIT
There is also an additional interface `IWebHostEnvironment` that can be used in ASP.NET Core applications. This is available in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` namespace.

Comment: a quick typo in above answer, IHostingEnvironment is replaced by IWebHostEnvironment. and a new namespace needs to be used "using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;".

Comment: What is the difference between `IHostEnvironment` and `IWebHostEnviornment` asked myself: 
`Use IHostEnvironment where possible, and use IWebHostEnvironment when you need access to the WebRootPath or WebRootFileProvider properties.` https://andrewlock.net/ihostingenvironment-vs-ihost-environment-obsolete-types-in-net-core-3/

Comment: They could have made this a lot simpler!

Answer (score 85):

> When `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` was introduced in 2.1 some types like `IHostingEnvironment` and `IApplicationLifetime` were copied from **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`**. Some 3.0 changes cause apps to include both the **`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`** and **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`** namespaces. Any use of those duplicate types causes an "ambiguous reference" compiler error when both namespaces are referenced.
>
> This error has been addressed in **3.0.0-preview3** by marking the following types obsolete and replacing them with new types. There have not been any behavioral changes made for the new types, only naming.
>
> Obsolete types (warning):
>
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment`
> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment`
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime`
> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime`
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.EnvironmentName`
> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.EnvironmentName`
>
> New types:
>
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment`
> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment : IHostEnvironment`
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime`
> `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Environments`
>
> Note the new IHostEnvironment IsDevelopment, IsProduction, etc. extension methods are in the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting namespace which may need to be added to your app.
>
> For 3.0 both the old and new types will be available from HostBulder's and WebHostBuilder's dependency injection containers. The old types will be removed in 4.0.

Source: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7749

Long and short, you're looking for `IWebHostEnvironment` now. You'll likely need to add using for `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` as well.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft has pointed out that .NET CORE 4.0 will be skipped in order to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.0. Instead, the next version after .NET Core 3.x is .NET 5.0. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md

Comment: That was clipped from the Microsoft support document. At the time, they hadn't announced .NET 5 yet.

Answer (score 5):

From ASP.NET Core 5, use:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    if (Environments.Development.Equals(env.EnvironmentName))
    {
        ...
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer or other highly upvoted answers? It seems like the same guidance but with less explanation.

Comment: @JeremyCaney  Yes, this would certainly be a better answer if some explanation was included, and code-only answers are necessarily incomplete answers. But the OP provided some code, and then explicitly asked: "_What is the correct way to do this now?_". While other answers and comments provided discussion and detail of ASP.NET changes, this is the only answer which directly responds to the question that was asked, by posting the revised code. None of the other answers or comments provided a revised implementation of `Configure()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

For `env.IsDevelopment()`, I used `env.EnvironmentName.Equals("Development")`

Comment: It's much better to use `IHostEnvironment` and then you get direct access to the `IsDevelopment()` extension method.

Answer (score 2):

The type IHostingEnvironment is obsolete for ASP.NET Core 3.0+. And according to Microsoft:

> The recommended alternative is
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.**IWebHostEnvironment**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-7.0

IHostingEnvironment is obsolete for following versions as of today:
[image]