# The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .NET Core 3.0.100 ; Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.4.0 Preview 1.0 ; Blazor-server (official release).

I am trying to add Authentication and Authorization to my Blazor-server web app. I am reading the guideline at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project

(I also read this https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1825)

Then I right-click on Project, choose `Add` \ `New Scaffolded Item...`

I read the file `ScaffoldingReadme.txt`, then follow the guide.

I press F5 for debugging, I catch the error.

```
Severity:       Error
Error Code:     CS0246
Description:    The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Project:        foo
File:       C:\Users\donhuvy\Desktop\foo\bar\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml.g.cs
Line:       455
Suppression State:  Active
```

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot of vscode with the error]

Because file `\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml.g.cs` stand inside Razor Class Library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI (3.0.0)`, I cannot edit it.

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602072/5233410

Comment: It already is an issue: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13120

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is an issue,

The code generate is

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Environment
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine
```

it is missing `@using`

it should be

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
```

I reported issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/1094

Answer (score 11):

Issue solved by adding in our csproj file (3.1 core app):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Strange but worked!!!