# .NET Blazor scaffolded identity item compilation error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to customize **login** and **register** pages provided by .net for my `blazor` application. I'm trying to generate the hidden source code ([based on this documentation by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)) :

1- right click on solution.

2- add new item.

3- add new scaffolded item.

4- choose identity.

5- check login and register pages and choose data context class then click add.

[image]

I note that files generated but I got compilation error :

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IWebHostEnvironment' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   BlazorApp1  C:\Users**\source\repos\testtt\BlazorApp1\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Shared_Layout.cshtml.g.c

Comment: Be precise about the Blazor version(s). Thsi changed quickly.

Comment: See the workaround here, https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13120 - you will need only parts of it now.

Comment: I could reproduce the same issue with VS Enterprise 2019 (Version16.3.6) + ASP.NET Core 3.0.100. It seems a known issue: see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204049/the-type-or-namespace-name-iwebhostenvironment-could-not-be-found-are-you-mis/58204848#58204848) and [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Scaffolding/issues/1094). Adding a `@using` fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue fixed by adding @using. you saved my time.